# Simple C program in Elastic beanstalk

Tags: java, c, amazon-web-services, java-native-interface, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I think what I'm trying to do ought to be trivially easy for anyone who knows what they're doing, but the only language almost without exception that I've ever programmed in is C.  I do so poorly.  I'm trying to create a webapp on elastic beanstalk that talks to a C program.  My current plan is to use JNI to create a native function that I can call on the main jsp page when someone fills out a form and presses a button.

So far on the C end I've written a function that contains the 7 input variables and the 7 output variables needed for the C program to do everything it needs to do.  I don't need to access a database or do anything hard, I just need to pass 7 variables in and 7 variables out.

I've set up a java class that has a native method.  I gave it a main function that sticks in dummy variables and prints out the results.  The JNI works when I compile it all in one directory without any package names or anything that complicates it (I can't get it to work with package names.)  So I have a .so file, and a .class file and that all works.

On the other end I've taken the initial introduction webapp that AWS gives you.  Downloaded it to my machine and unpackaged the war file (Eclipse adds a bunch of boilerplate and structuring and I have no confidence in my ability to further complicate it with new tools like ant or something to do the compiling (I'm very comfortable with javac, javah and jar, thank you very much)). I've created a form on the index .jsp page and some javascript which takes input variables performs a function on them then sticks output data on the form.

As far as I can tell all I need to do now is call the java class from .jsp and that should link the whole thing together. I understand that there may be a better way to do this.  If I'm violating some deep principle of webapp programming or there is a security problem, let me know.  (I'll go ahead and sanitize my data inputs for example).   I can't seem to figure out exactly how to do it.  An example of a hello world doing this would be very helpful.  Do I need to stick anything in the web.xml file?  I kind of vaguely know that the .class file goes in the classes directory.  Where does the .so file go?

In summary:
Is there a simpler way to do what I'm doing (fewer languages/programs/lines of code?) 
(I know there are *better* ways)
Is what I'm doing dangerous in some fashion?
How do I call a java class from index.jsp?
Does web.xml have to have anything?
How do I compile the JNI to find the .so file somewhere other than the .class file?
Can I stick the .so file in with the class file?

Answer (score 0):

I'd put the .so file inside  $CATALINA_HOME/shared/lib folder wherever that may be.

If you don't want to put it there, maybe you want to specify the value of java.library.path as one of the options passed to the java runtime environment (e.g. java -Djava.library.path=/path/to/my.so ... ), this means you probably need to hack the tomcat launcher, or you could add this option to the JAVA_OPTS environment variable.